# Why is ThreadPoolTaskExecutor terminated immediately?

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have a problem in thread execution in Spring application. For some reason, the default instance (I don't create my own) of `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor` is terminated either immediately or after the first start of a new thread. No more than one thread is executed.

```
public class NotifiTask implements Runnable {

    private final NewPriceEvent event;
    private final PriceListenerNotifiable listener;

    public NotifiTask(
            PriceListenerNotifiable listener, NewPriceEvent event
    ) {
        this.listener = AssertUtils.notNull(listener, "listener");
        this.event = AssertUtils.notNull(event, "event");
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        this.listener.notifyNewPriceEvent(events);
    }

}
```

How I call executor to execute new thread:

```
executor.execute(new NotifiTask(listener, this.prices.peekLast()));
```

It throws this error:

> Executor [java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@440f0dfb[Terminated,
> pool size = 0, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks =
> 0]

For debugging purposes I'm dumping setting of executor before and after execution of my `NotifiTask` thread:

```
final ThreadPoolTaskExecutor exe = (ThreadPoolTaskExecutor) executor;

s.put("SimpleName", exe.getClass().getSimpleName());
s.put("Terminated", exe.getThreadPoolExecutor().isTerminated());
s.put("Terminating", exe.getThreadPoolExecutor().isTerminating());
s.put("ActiveCount", exe.getActiveCount());
s.put("CorePoolSize", exe.getCorePoolSize());
s.put("MaxPoolSize", exe.getMaxPoolSize());
s.put("QueueCapacity", exe.getQueueCapacity());
```

And this is a result:

> {Terminating=false, SimpleName=ThreadPoolTaskExecutor,
> MaxPoolSize=2147483647, ActiveCount=0, QueueCapacity=2147483647,
> CorePoolSize=8, Terminated=true}

The problem is with `Terminated=true` + when I get an exception all configuration values are set to 0.

For what reason is / should be `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor` terminated without any request? Why did it reset the executor setting?

Comment: Probably you get an exception in the run method. Try to add an UncaughtExceptionHandler.

Comment: @Mar-Z Unfortunately, it was not an exception, I checked it and none is thrown.

Comment: where do you get the `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor` instance from?

Comment: @cyberbrain Instance is created by Spring itself, I wire it as Spring Bean (I double checked and injected instance is absolutely correct, problem is elsewhere)

Comment: Is the instance used somewhere else? Or the `.execute(...` called twice? Default config is a single thread - see [ThreadPoolTaskExecutor JavaDocs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/concurrent/ThreadPoolTaskExecutor.html) -  so according to your debug dump, you are _not_ using the default configuration for that: "CorePoolSize=8" from you vs. "The default configuration is a core pool size of 1" from the docs.

Comment: Maybe you can use Spring Boots actuator to get the current config values - and find out where they come from. See [Discover Built-in Options for External Properties](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.17.RELEASE/reference/html/howto-properties-and-configuration.html#howto-discover-build-in-options-for-external-properties)